# Use Powershell Script to Share Drives over Local Network

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, script, network-shares

I find it convenient to share drives between my computers over my home network. I do this by right clicking on the drive and changing the advanced sharing "Share Permissions" to NETWORK. I am wanting to achieve the exact same thing using a PowerShell script, but I don't quite understand how to. I'm wanting to achieve the equivalent of the following:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3msU7rNf3bA&feature=youtu.be

How would I do this with a PowerShell script?

Comment: What have you tried?  We do not write PowerShell scripts for people.  All we can do is help you diagnose a script's behavior, questions seeking us to write a script for you, is out of scope here at Super User and Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this using the

```
New-SmbShare
```

cmdlet. More information, releated cmdlets and examples can be found on [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/new-smbshare)